# How to select a number of rows according to a column

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

So I have got two columns in an Oracle database:

```
Name / count
```

I would like to print the name x times, x being the count.

```
E.g. Paul / 5 would mean Paul being printed 5 times.
     Sam / 6 would mean Sam being printed 6 times
```

Tried `row_number` over but not sure how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use connect by as following:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE AS
  2  (SELECT 'paul' as NAME, 5 AS COUNT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'sam' as NAME, 6 AS COUNT FROM DUAL
  4  ) -- YOUR ACTUAL QUERY STARTS FROM LINE#5
  5  Select t.name, m.lvl
  6  from your_table t
  7  join
  8  (Select level as lvl
  9  from
 10    (Select max(count) as maxcount
 11     from your_table)
 12  Connect by level <= maxcount) m
 13  On (t.count >= m.lvl)
 14  ORDER BY 1,2;

NAME        LVL
---- ----------
paul          1
paul          2
paul          3
paul          4
paul          5
sam           1
sam           2
sam           3
sam           4
sam           5
sam           6

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

you need recursive query to achieve this.

```
with cte(nam, ctr) as (
    select 'Paul' as nam, 5 as ctr from dual
    union all
    select 'Sam', 6 as ctr from dual
),
cte2(nam, ct, ctr) as (
    select nam, 1 as ct, ctr from cte
    union all
    select nam, ct + 1, ctr from cte2
    where ct<ctr
)select nam, ct from cte2  
order by nam asc
```

**output:**

[image]

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0be1c/29504/1)

Comment: Thanks! it works fine but it doesn't seem to go with the rest of my code very well. (I have a large piece of code where I want to insert this bit in) Any other recommendations?

Comment: i need to see your code, only way to generate N rows is to use cte, for loop or cursors.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select  name
  from  Table1,
        (select  level lvl
           from  dual
           connect by level <= (select max(cnt) from Table1 )
        )
  where lvl <= cnt
  order by name;
```

check fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14a67/1

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option (your query starts at line #4):

```
SQL> with your_table as
  2    (select 'paul' as name, 5 as count from dual union all
  3     select 'sam'  as name, 6 as count from dual)
  4  select name
  5  from your_table cross join table (cast (multiset (select level from dual
  6                                                    connect by level <= count
  7                                                   ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

NAME
----
paul
paul
paul
paul
paul
sam
sam
sam
sam
sam
sam

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `connect by level <= some_number` logic containing `cross join` to link with your table `tab` :

```
with tab(Name,"count") as
( select 'Paul', 5 from dual union all select 'Sam', 6 from dual )
 select name, level as seq 
   from dual d
  cross join tab t
connect by level <= t."count"
    and prior name = name
    and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cae9f1c38af25ade33e949cd61f09ae5)</kbd>